# CKEditor.replace not working

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

For some reason CKEditor stopped loading, the same thing happening in this 
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/qp2vkez5/1/)

```
CKEDITOR.replace('test')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped loading"? Your jsFiddle is working here. May you check your browser console for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor not loading in just Opera, can't tell when and why this happened. All other JS is working properly. So if someone else faces this problem try other browsers.

Comment: I'm guessing that you use Opera 12. A browser that's 2 years old and is not supported any more (mainly because it uses the old engine that's been dropped by Opera Software).